# Call Local Java libraries from HTML

Tags: java, html, web-applications

I have a java instalation package  (jars with necessary support files in local system) , is it possible to call a function(in java installtion package) from html ?  or any other supporting technologies

eg: in my local system,  i will have (C:\myapp\lib\test.jar), i need to make a call to a method in the jar from html .
which technology can be used to enable this .

A web app(servlet container) will be used to generate the html code

Comment: You should more about servlet[http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html]. Servlet tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Comment: generating html is not a problem . I need to call a java method in the client side . eg: need to access a device throught some API

Answer (score 1):

Q: Do you want to run your .jar client side (as an applet), or server side (as a servlet)?

It sounds like you want to execute an Applet on the client's PC.  It also sounds like you want to read and write to the user's filesystem, which requires special privileges.

Here is a good article on creating a "trusted applet":

- http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm

See also:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc1.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html
  *

Comment: I need to run it from client side, and is there any other way other than an applet ?

Comment: There's also Java WebStart: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/